# PHP: Strtotime / date ignoring timezone?

Tags: php, strtotime

having some trouslb with strtotime, its easier to show by example :)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');             //  Set timezone to local / 
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("1-6-2003"));   // Expected: 01/06/2003    Got:    01/06/2003
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("16-12-2003")); // Expected: 16/12/2003    Got:    16/12/2003
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("10-12-03"));   // Expected: 10/12/2003    Got:    03/12/2010
```

Any ideas how to get around this problem? I am using strtotime to try and negate problems with users entering dates in different formats.

Thank you for reading,

Rik.

Comment: It's not a problem with timezones, but with date formats.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` does not support that kind of date format. See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for a list of supported formats. Read the documentation next time.

Comment: I did read the docs, hence using - as the delimiter instead of / to avoid US style date formats. Got around the issue by doing some checking and fudging of the string and inserting a missing 19 or 20 manually before processing through strtotime :)